# Cycle Time Simulink

Tags: matlab, controller, code-generation, microcontroller, simulink

I have to generate code from a Simulink program to be flashed into a controller. The controller must have a cycle time of around 10ms. 
How do I set it in Simulink? Just by setting the solver step to 10ms?

Answer (score 0):

The solver should be set to fixed-step / discrete, with a step of 0.01 :

[image]